# Java AWS SDK 2.x Async Client - can’t override thread pool executor

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-sdk, completable-future

I want to set custom thread pool executor for Async Client (e.g. `SnsAsyncClient`) for AWS SDK 2.x. I see that for AWS SDK 1.x there is exist `withExecutorFactory` on client builder, and for 2.x we need to set up `ClientAsyncConfiguration` and invoke `asyncConfiguration` method on client builder:

```
ClientAsyncConfiguration.Builder asyncConfig = ClientAsyncConfiguration.builder()
        .advancedOptions(Map.of(SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR,
                myCustomExecutor));
SnsAsyncClient.builder()
        .asyncConfiguration(asyncConfig.build())
        .build();
```

Still, custom thread pool executor not applies. I expect that all async calls and subsequent calls on `CompletableFuture` will be executed on custom executor, but it’s not true.
During debug, I see that logic executes on different thread pools: `aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-X`, `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-X`. 
Example of AWS SNS async call:

```
snsAsyncClient.publish(publishRequest)
        .thenApplyAsync(..)
        .whenCompleteAsync(..);
```

How to setup custom thread pool, so async non-blocking IO operations will be executed on specific thread pool?

AWS SDK version:    `software.amazon.awssdk sdk-core 2.7.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of async configuration `SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR` is to provide thread pool executor, which will be used for subsequent calls on `CompletableFuture` like `thenApply(..)` and `whenComplete(..)`. This executor will not be applied for methods like `thenApplyAsync` and `whenCompleteAsync` due to `CompletableFuture` implementation (if executor not passed into `thenApplyAsync`, it will be used by default `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, or we could pass custom executor as a second method argument).

```
snsAsyncClient.publish(publishRequest)
        .thenApply(..)
        .whenComplete(..);
```

code inside `thenApply` and `whenComplete` will be processed on configured executor from `FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR`.

In order to set up an asynchronous client configuration and improve performance, we should create instance of `NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder` and pass it into async client using method `httpClientBuilder`

```
var asyncHttpClientBuilder = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
        .maxConcurrency(100)
        .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
        .connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
SnsAsyncClient.builder()
        .httpClientBuilder(asyncHttpClientBuilder)
        .build();
```